# ItemViewModel: method code is too large

Tags: tornadofx

I have a database table with 270 columns I need to work with. I wrote some code generators to help me keep my sanity, but I have an issue with ItemViewModel class - it refuses to compile with 'Method code too large' exception.

The class is plain:

```
class F321PModel: ItemViewModel<F321P>() {
    val id = bind(F321P::idProperty)
    // 269 more lines below
```

I receive method too large exception even for 50 columns. Is bind introduces so huge overhead ? I don't think that 50 columns table is something extreme, maybe it is possible to optimize something ?

Here is problem classes https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d0978899ad569839797b025ad081bbf7

```
Error:Kotlin: [Internal Error] java.lang.RuntimeException: Error generating class file ru/abinet/blt/updateapplication/models/F321PModel.class (compiled from [C:\Users\hachatryan\IdeaProjects\updateapplication\src\main\kotlin\ru\abinet\blt\updateapplication\models\321PModel.kt]): Method code too large!
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClassFileFactory$OutputClassFile.asByteArray(ClassFileFactory.java:255)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.output.outputUtils.OutputUtilsKt.writeAll(outputUtils.kt:32)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.output.outputUtils.OutputUtilsKt.writeAll(outputUtils.kt:42)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.writeOutput(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:98)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.access$writeOutput(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:67)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$createOutputFilesFlushingCallbackIfPossible$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:107)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$createOutputFilesFlushingCallbackIfPossible$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:67)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.GenerationStateKt$GenerationStateEventCallback$1.invoke(GenerationState.kt:259)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.GenerationStateKt$GenerationStateEventCallback$1.invoke(GenerationState.kt:258)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.GenerationState.afterIndependentPart(GenerationState.kt:215)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generate(PackageCodegenImpl.java:67)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.generatePackage(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:100)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.doGenerateFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:78)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:45)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:450)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:152)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:158)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:61)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:107)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:51)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:92)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:380)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:892)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:919)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:891)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:378)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Method code too large!
at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.getSize(MethodWriter.java:2036)
at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.toByteArray(ClassWriter.java:850)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClassBuilderFactories$2.asBytes(ClassBuilderFactories.java:126)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DelegatingClassBuilderFactory.asBytes(DelegatingClassBuilderFactory.kt:36)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DelegatingClassBuilderFactory.asBytes(DelegatingClassBuilderFactory.kt:36)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DelegatingClassBuilderFactory.asBytes(DelegatingClassBuilderFactory.kt:36)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClassFileFactory$ClassBuilderAndSourceFileList.asBytes(ClassFileFactory.java:287)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClassFileFactory$OutputClassFile.asByteArray(ClassFileFactory.java:252)
... 45 more
```

Comment: Please post the complete error message and stack trace.

Comment: I've updated my post, but nothing in stack trace points to tornadofx.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this same error with ~60 properties, I managed to get around it by wrapping each `bind` call in a `lazy` delegate:

```
val id: LongProperty by lazy<LongProperty> {
    bind(F321P::idProperty)
}
```